# Facebook Password Store Intimating user

Tags: android, ios, facebook

Hey guys I am really newbie with the Facebook Login structure, my main goal is to maintain session of facebook and open feed (not the data obtained using JSON) in our own application.

Is it any good way to maintain session of facebook in our own application and open feed in webview everytime whenever needed.

I was wondering with store password methodology for facebook. Is it a good way to get user Facebook Email-Id and password stored in our app asking credentials in edittext and crypting password using AES Crytography. Though app will intimate that we are storing password which would be solidly crypted.

And the stored email-id and password can be to login to facebook using javascript.

Thanks in advance. Help me out with this.

Comment: Facebook Platform Policy doesn't allow you to even ask for email/password

Comment: Hey @WizKid then is there any way to show facebook feeds in our own app same as facebook app does (means layout same as facebook), I know we can get data using Graph API in JSON formats but I need same look and feel ?